# Can i use javascript to click this selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Javascript to click on the selection below.

```
<div class="CRControllerAddButton">
    <u colspan="2">Add Access Time</u>
</div>
```

And i am trying to use `document.getElementById('CRControllerAddButton').click();`

How come i cant get it to work? Is it because its a class? I just need to click on the div is all at least to work.

What javascript would be used in lets say console on chrome to do this?

Below is the entire code if needed where its nested.

```
 <div id="CRbodyaccesspolicyid" layer="0" class="CRController_body" style="width: 360px; top: 444px; left: 469px;">
  <div style="width:100%;background:#FFF;" align="center">
    <input type="text" class="CRsearchtext" id="CRSearchTextaccesspolicyid">
  </div>
  <div id="CRControllerDataaccesspolicyid" style="overflow: auto; height: 61px;">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div class="CRControllerAddButton"><u colspan="2">Add Access Time</u></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td title="Allowed all the time" style="width: 50%;"><input type="radio" id="chkaccesspolicyid_1" name="radioaccesspolicyid" key="1" label="Allowed all the time" style="float: left;">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 134px; white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 2px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Allowed all the time</div></td>
          <td title="Denied all the time" style="width: 50%;"><input type="radio" id="chkaccesspolicyid_2" name="radioaccesspolicyid" key="2" label="Denied all the time" style="float: left;">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 134px; white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 2px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Denied all the time</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td title="Allowed only during Work Hours" style="width: 50%;"><input type="radio" id="chkaccesspolicyid_3" name="radioaccesspolicyid" key="3" label="Allowed only during Work Hours" style="float: left;">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 134px; white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 2px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Allowed only during Work Hours</div></td>
          <td title="Denied during Work  hours" style="width: 50%;"><input type="radio" id="chkaccesspolicyid_4" name="radioaccesspolicyid" key="4" label="Denied during Work  hours" style="float: left;">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 134px; white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 2px; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Denied during Work  hours</div></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="CRControllerButtonaccesspolicyid" align="center">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="&lt;&lt;" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="&lt;" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="OK">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="Cancel">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="&gt;" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="&gt;&gt;" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `id` matching "CRControllerAddButton" and as a result you attempt to click `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's because it's a class, not an id. But there is a function to get all elements having a given class: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName).

Use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('CRControllerAddButton')[0].click();
```

There's a `[0]` because as there can be more than one elements, this function returns a live nodelist which works about like an array.

If you want to click on all elements having this class, loop on the live nodelist returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Nada it gaveme an error `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByClassName'`

Comment: It didnt choose the right link it opened somethign else? Any idea?

Comment: Its openeing one of the other buttons i have thats already named that. How can i specifically choose this one?

Comment: In the HTML you show, the element with that class isn't a link.

Comment: Nevermind i got it! Its `document.getElementsByClassName('CRControllerAddButton')[4].click();`

Comment: Thank you again! Ill check it off in a few minutes!

Comment: @sonicboom The cleanest would probably be to give an id to your link. But *why* do you want to automatically click a link ?

Comment: Creating a script to automatically do something for me on a router.